# Graphviz - AttributeError: object has no attribute 'partition'

Tags: python, django, graphviz

I'm using [graphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) with my Django models to render graphs from the following python script for each automata:

```
alphabets = automata.alphabet_set.all()
states = automata.states_set.all()
transitions = automata.transition_set.all()
dot = gv.Graph()
for state in states:
    dot.node(state.state, state.state)
for transition in transitions:
    dot.edge(transition.current_state, transition.next_state, transition.input)
dot.render( automata.id + '.gv', view=True)
```

And these are my models:

```
class Automata(models.Model):
    pass

class Alphabet(models.Model):
    alphabet = models.CharField()
    automata = models.ForeignKey(Automata, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class States(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField()
    automata = models.ForeignKey(Automata, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Transition(models.Model):
    current_state = models.ForeignKey(States, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'current')
    input = models.ForeignKey(Alphabet, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    next_state = models.ForeignKey(States, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'next')
    automata = models.ForeignKey(Automata, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

but everytime I try to execute my script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_graph.py", line 36, in <module>
    dot.edge(transition.current_state, transition.next_state, transition.input)
  File "/home/nids/automata/auto/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphviz/dot.py", line 116, in edge
    tail_name = self.quote_edge(tail_name)
  File "/home/nids/automata/auto/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphviz/lang.py", line 63, in quote_edge
    node, _, rest = identifier.partition(':')
AttributeError: 'States' object has no attribute 'partition'
```

Knowing that I have no error if I simply do: `dot.edge('A', 'B', 'edge label')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graphvis` code is expecting a string to be passed into it, not a `States` object (your model).

You can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/blob/master/graphviz/lang.py#L51) in the `quote_edge` function.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks! Fixed by replacing it with `dot.edge(transition.current_state.state, transition.next_state.state, transition.input.alphabet)`

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help out!